# Code Migrations is skipping initial code migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Using Entity Framework 5, we're using Code-First Migrations in our application. Every developer has his own database on which they work.

I have accidently emptied mine: There is nothing in there anymore, no tables, not even the migration history table.

So, I've tried to update the database again through the PM console by executing `update-database`. It immediatley gives me an error that a table does not exist, while it should be created in my inital code migration.

What is interesting is that the PM console also shows what migrations are being applied, which does not contain the inital create code migration, thus not creating any tables at all, and ofcourse failing at later migrations.

I tried executing `update-database -targetmigration:initialcreate` which gives me the message that that code migration does not exist, while it is a direct copy/paste from the cs file, so the id must be correct (note: this works for other migrations).

I also tried `update-database -targetmigration:0` and `update-database -targetmigration: $InitialDatabase` which both give me `'Target database is already at version 0'`.

I've also tried deleting the database altogether and let EF create it for, didnt work either, it keeps skipping the initialcreate migration.

So how do I get Code Migrations to execute my initalCreate code migration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with EF migrations in a team scenario is not ideal to say the least. The best practice my team follows is to *never* commit migrations. Migrations are personal and apply only to your particular database instance. If everyone commits their own migrations you end up with a mess, quick.

While not directly related to your question, some may wonder how you deal with production migrations. Simply, you don't. Your Release Manager, or whoever will actually push the release live, should generate SQL to apply *all* the changes at once, and then hand this off to your DBA, or whoever manages the production database.

That said, in the scenario that you describe, where you database has been emptied. The best fix is to delete all migrations in your Migrations folder. Even and especially, the initial migration (they don't matter, anyways, because you shouldn't be holding on to them outside of your personal codebase). Then generate a new migration, which will trigger EF to compare your current database state (empty) with the state of the app and essentially create a new initial migration based on the current state of your app. Then, you can apply this migration.

Comment: This approach seems logical and fail-safe, I've never thought about it this way. It's true that Code Migrations in a team scenario doesn't always work out great. We will consider using this approach in our next project. Also, the solution you provided for the empty database did work out great. thanks!! :)